# Criando background services no ionic com cordova ou java

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Tenho uma aplicação que comecei a fazer com ionic. A priori será compilada apenas para android. Nessa aplicação o usuário efetuará alguns cadastros, que ficarão salvos localmente e a cada hora um serviço em background deve tentar sincronizar o banco com um servidor (um post). Concluí todas as etapas com sucesso e deixei essa parte do background por último.

Estou utilizando o plugin [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) para realizar essa tarefa. No entanto, mesmo testando repetidas vezes todas as combinações possíveis, eu percebi que embora a aplicação fique em segundo plano e execute o que eu preciso, em algum momento o android finaliza a aplicação (liberar memória por exemplo). E isso faz com que todos os serviços em segundo plano deixem de ser executados até que a aplicação seja aberta e colocada em segundo plano novamente.

Eu já criei serviços que rodam em background (services e broadcasts receivers) com java para android nativo, mas a aplicação atual é relativamente grande e uma mudança agora seria inviável.

Meu código, no arquivo app.js está assim:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage', 'ionic-material'])

  .run(function ($ionicPlatform, LocalizacaoService, $http) {

    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }, 1000);

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        //StatusBar.styleDefault();
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
      }

    })

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.overrideBackButton();
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.excludeFromTaskList();

      //cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({silent: true});
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
        title: "My App",
        text: "Something here",
      });
      // Enable background mode
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive();

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function () {
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
      });

      // Run when the device is ready
      // Called when background mode has been activated
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

        //localizacao a cada  5 min
        //localiza, salva e envia tudo
        setInterval(function () {
          //executa uma tarefa   
          console.log("executou")

        }, 10000);
        //sinc de visitas a cada 30 min
        setInterval(function () {
          //executa outra
          console.log('executou');

        }, 18000);
      }

    }, false);

  });
```

Minhas dúvidas são: minha implementação do plugin está errada? ou, existe a possibilidade de depois do código android ser criado, um service com android nativo ser implementado no código?

Comment: Estou no Ionic 2 que nada tem a ver com o Ionic 1, mas acredito eu, como no Android nativo, você tem acordar seu serviço de vez em quando, pois acaba, inacreditavelmente dormindo. Nesse plugin ai que você está usando tem o `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.wakeUp();` ... Dê uma olhada de como fazer isso lá no https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: Me veio a ideia de usar o wakeUp(), mas em que momento você acha que seria viável executar isso? Pois se a aplicação estiver fechada/morta não será executado. certo?

Comment: Você consegue descobrir quando ela fecha? Se não, executa de minuto em minuto e vê se pesa muito.

Comment: Talvez você devesse pensar em sincronizar se app com seu banco apenas quando ele estiver em utilização, ficar deixando ele como um serviço de fundo fazendo request não é algo aconselhável e muito menos legal uma vez que você vai usar a banda do seu usuário de forma constante sem que ele saiba/queria e sem contar no consumo a mais de energia que seu aplicativo vai gerar, esses dois fatores podem gerar uma fuga de usuários muito grande uma vez que pode não ser difícil de perceber que foi após a instalação do seu app ou pelos gráficos de utilização de bateria e banda do android.

Comment: Recomendo que dê uma olhada nesse exemplo: https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Using-the-MyService-Sample
Acredito que seja exatamente o que você está querendo fazer.